# WinSCP script sending file, but not file contents

Tags: winscp

I created a WinSCP script to send a text file from a SQL server to a Raspberry Pi which displays the data on a screen. The file is updated and sent once every minute via batch using this file, (renamed some identifying text):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"
/log=C:\localfilepath\send_file_log.log
-command "option batch on" "option confirm off" "open sftp://user:pass@XXX.XXX.XXX.250:22 -hostkey=*"
"put C:\localfilepath\SQL_results_2.txt /remotefilepath/SQL_results.txt" "close" "exit"
```

This worked fine for a few days, but all of a sudden it stopped working, I hadn't changed anything since I set it running a few days before. It still successfully uploads the file, but the file is completely blank. It doesn't produce any error messages when it runs, either in the command prompt, or in the WinSCP log file.

I have tried setting permissions on the file to 0777 via chmod, and the issue persists, so it's not a permissions issue of that type. I have also tried restarting the Pi, just in case.

What could cause the uploaded file to be blank?

---

**EDIT:** I appear unable to edit the file via the WinSCP GUI either, I will edit the file and save it, but no changes take effect. Seems like it might not be a WinSCP issue after all so I will look further.

---

**EDIT 2:** Issue is resolved. Turns out it was a space issue as suggested in the comments. Apologies for this silly question.

---

WinSCP log file contents below:

```
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.327 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.328 WinSCP Version 5.7.5 (Build 5665) (OS 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1 - Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard)
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.328 Configuration: HKCU\Software\Martin Prikryl\WinSCP 2\
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.328 Log level: Normal
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.328 Local account: DOMAIN\USER
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.328 Working directory: C:\localfilepath
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.328 Process ID: 31624
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.328 Command-line: "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe" /console=575 /consoleinstance=_64720_717 "/log=C:\localfilepath\send_file_log.log" "-command" "option batch on" "option confirm off" "open sftp://user:pass@XXX.XXX.XXX.250:22 -hostkey=*" "put C:\localfilepath\SQL_results_2.txt /remotefilepath/SQL_results.txt" "close" "exit" 
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Time zone: Current: GMT-7, Standard: GMT-7 (Mountain Standard Time), DST: GMT-6 (Mountain Daylight Time), DST Start: 3/11/2018, DST End: 11/4/2018
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Login time: Tuesday, January 02, 2018 8:57:57 AM
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Script: Retrospectively logging previous script records:
> 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Script: option batch on
< 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Script: batch           on        
< 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Script: reconnecttime   120       
> 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Script: option confirm off
< 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Script: confirm         off       
> 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Script: open sftp://user:***@XXX.XXX.XXX.250:22 -hostkey=*
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Session name: user@XXX.XXX.XXX.250 (Ad-Hoc site)
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Host name: XXX.XXX.XXX.250 (Port: 22)
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 User name: user (Password: Yes, Key file: No)
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Tunnel: No
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Transfer Protocol: SFTP
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Ping type: -, Ping interval: 30 sec; Timeout: 15 sec
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Disable Nagle: No
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Proxy: none
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Send buffer: 262144
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 SSH protocol version: 2; Compression: No
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Bypass authentication: No
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Try agent: Yes; Agent forwarding: No; TIS/CryptoCard: No; KI: Yes; GSSAPI: No
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Ciphers: aes,blowfish,3des,WARN,arcfour,des; Ssh2DES: No
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 KEX: dh-gex-sha1,dh-group14-sha1,dh-group1-sha1,rsa,WARN
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 SSH Bugs: A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Simple channel: Yes
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.329 Return code variable: Autodetect; Lookup user groups: A
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 Shell: default
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 EOL: 0, UTF: 2
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 Clear aliases: Yes, Unset nat.vars: Yes, Resolve symlinks: Yes
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 LS: ls -la, Ign LS warn: Yes, Scp1 Comp: No
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 SFTP Bugs: A,A
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 SFTP Server: default
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 Local directory: default, Remote directory: home, Update: Yes, Cache: Yes
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 Cache directory changes: Yes, Permanent: Yes
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 DST mode: 1
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.330 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.331 Looking up host "XXX.XXX.XXX.250"
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.331 Connecting to XXX.XXX.XXX.250 port 22
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.458 Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.0p1 Debian-4+deb7u6
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.458 Using SSH protocol version 2
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.459 We claim version: SSH-2.0-WinSCP_release_5.7.5
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.475 Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
. 2018-01-02 08:57:57.546 Doing Diffie-Hellman key exchange with hash SHA-256
. 2018-01-02 08:57:59.941 Verifying host key rsa2 **************************************
. 2018-01-02 08:57:59.942 Host key matches cached key
. 2018-01-02 08:57:59.942 Host key fingerprint is:
. 2018-01-02 08:57:59.942 ssh-rsa 2048 ***********************************
. 2018-01-02 08:57:59.943 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR client->server encryption
. 2018-01-02 08:57:59.943 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 client->server MAC algorithm
. 2018-01-02 08:57:59.943 Initialised AES-256 SDCTR server->client encryption
. 2018-01-02 08:57:59.943 Initialised HMAC-SHA-256 server->client MAC algorithm
! 2018-01-02 08:57:59.954 Using username "user".
. 2018-01-02 08:58:04.971 Prompt (password, "SSH password", <no instructions>, "&Password: ")
. 2018-01-02 08:58:04.971 Using stored password.
. 2018-01-02 08:58:04.972 Sent password
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.197 Access granted
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.197 Opening session as main channel
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.208 Opened main channel
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.272 Started a shell/command
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.273 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.273 Using SFTP protocol.
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.274 Doing startup conversation with host.
> 2018-01-02 08:58:05.274 Type: SSH_FXP_INIT, Size: 5, Number: -1
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.294 Type: SSH_FXP_VERSION, Size: 124, Number: -1
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 SFTP version 3 negotiated.
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 Unknown server extension posix-rename@openssh.com="1"
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 Supports statvfs@openssh.com extension version "2"
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 Unknown server extension fstatvfs@openssh.com="2"
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 Supports hardlink@openssh.com extension version "1"
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 We believe the server has signed timestamps bug
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 We will use UTF-8 strings until server sends an invalid UTF-8 string as with SFTP version 3 and older UTF-8 string are not mandatory
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 Limiting packet size to OpenSSH sftp-server limit of 262148 bytes
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 Getting current directory name.
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 Getting real path for '.'
> 2018-01-02 08:58:05.295 Type: SSH_FXP_REALPATH, Size: 10, Number: 16
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.325 Type: SSH_FXP_NAME, Size: 37, Number: 16
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.325 Real path is '/home/user'
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.325 Startup conversation with host finished.
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.326 Script: Active session: [1] user@XXX.XXX.XXX.250
> 2018-01-02 08:58:05.326 Script: put C:\localfilepath\SQL_results_2.txt /remotefilepath/SQL_results.txt
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.327 Copying 1 files/directories to remote directory "/remotefilepath/"
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.327   PrTime: Yes; PrRO: No; Rght: rw-r--r--; PrR: No (No); FnCs: N; RIC: 0100; Resume: S (102400); CalcS: No; Mask: SQL_results.txt
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.327   TM: B; ClAr: No; RemEOF: No; RemBOM: No; CPS: 0; NewerOnly: No; InclM: ; ResumeL: 0
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.327   AscM: *.*html; *.htm; *.txt; *.php; *.php3; *.cgi; *.c; *.cpp; *.h; *.pas; *.bas; *.tex; *.pl; *.js; .htaccess; *.xtml; *.css; *.cfg; *.ini; *.sh; *.xml
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.328 File: 'C:\localfilepath\SQL_results_2.txt' [2018-01-02T15:40:55.783Z] [492]
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.328 Copying "C:\localfilepath\SQL_results_2.txt" to remote directory started.
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.328 Binary transfer mode selected.
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.329 Opening remote file.
> 2018-01-02 08:58:05.329 Type: SSH_FXP_OPEN, Size: 94, Number: 259
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.362 Type: SSH_FXP_HANDLE, Size: 13, Number: 259
> 2018-01-02 08:58:05.363 Type: SSH_FXP_WRITE, Size: 517, Number: 774
> 2018-01-02 08:58:05.365 Type: SSH_FXP_CLOSE, Size: 13, Number: 1028
> 2018-01-02 08:58:05.365 Type: SSH_FXP_SETSTAT, Size: 90, Number: 521
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.417 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 774
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 1028
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Status code: 0
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Preserving timestamp [2018-01-02T15:40:55.000Z]
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Type: SSH_FXP_STATUS, Size: 24, Number: 521
< 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Status code: 0
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Transfer done: 'C:\localfilepath\SQL_results_2.txt' [492]
> 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Script: close
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Closing connection.
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.465 Sending special code: 12
. 2018-01-02 08:58:05.466 Sent EOF message
```

Comment: Post the log file. Also, can you get the server log?

Comment: Thanks, I've added the WinSCP logfile. What do you mean by server log?

Comment: Have you got enough disk space on your Raspberry Pi?  Does it work when run from the GUI?  Try setting the remote folder and then uploading.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Rasberry Pi but it's using the SFTP protocol which means there is a server supporting SFTP within it. This server should provide an FTP log much like the client log you posted here. The client log appears to believe the file uploaded successfully which means the server did something with the file the client is unaware of. The server log should reflect this.

Comment: @Bacon Bits I just tried from the GUI and my changes don't take effect, still no errors though. I am able to edit the file manually so I don't feel that space is an issue, however the PI says I am using 6.1GB of the 6.8GB available, but it claims this is 100% usage, so I will investigate that further.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, it turns out the issue was space, I assume that sending files via SFTP is generating enough logs to fill space pretty quickly. For now I have deleted the 750MB Wolfram Alpha program, which the Raspbian OS has built in, I'll have to find and purge the log files periodically to keep this from happening again.

Comment: If you cannot change the file in WinSCP GUI, you do not have a programming question.

Comment: @Martin Prikryl That is true. Technically Bacon Bits had the exact answer, and I found this by finding sthames42 SFTP logs. Not sure what the protocol is in this situation, perhaps the question should be deleted, but otherwise I will accept their comment as an answer should either of them post it as such.

Comment: I believe you can also post your own answer and take the credit yourself. You did find the problem, after all.